# What methods/apparatus are used to model the early Earth? What do we know of their accuracy?

Tags: geology, models, earth-history

A friend of mine asked our teacher but the class was over and in online mode, I can't ask my teacher until the next lecture. It sparked my curiosity, I know we use carbon dating for finding the age of organic material, snowball hypothesis is there and Theories of Oparin Haldane tell us about primitive atmospheric conditions. Is there anything I don't know about, it may be some method in geography? Just tell me the name of the method if you can't tell in detail, I'm stuck on it "Modeling early earth".

Comment: Carbon dating does not go back further than ~50 ka, you probably think of other, longer-lived isotopes.

Answer (score 1):

For dating old geological material, [zircon dating](https://www.amnh.org/learn-teach/curriculum-collections/earth-inside-and-out/zircon-chronology-dating-the-oldest-material-on-earth) is sometimes used. Also see [Uranium-lead dating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium%E2%80%93lead_dating). There is also data from Antarctic and Greenland [ice cores](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/features/Paleoclimatology_IceCores).

Other things you could look are [Earth formation theories](https://www.physics.mcgill.ca/%7Ehilke/181/pictures/AnswerQEarth.pdf) - the core accretion model & the disk instability model as well as [plate tectonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_tectonics) and [continental drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_drift).

There are also the [theories about the origin of water on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_water_on_Earth).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the work of John Valley at the University of Wisconsin.  He has dated zircons from the Jack Hills in Australia.  Now, he is analyzing glassy inclusions in zircons.  The inclusions are unaltered siliceous magma that formed the crust of the early earth. The American Geophysical Union published a volume of papers you should see.  The book "The Early Earth" is at https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118860359

Answer (score 0):

The oldest radioactive dating is uranium lead quantities and zircon. Oceanic fossils and minerals give us a estimate of height of primitive oceans. And the oxide mineral contents of geologic strata give us estimate of how much carbon and oxygen were in our primitive atmosphere.